# Python: How to join dictionaries in for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

is there any way to join dictionaries as a result in for loop.
Here is my sample code:

```
for value in data['actions']:
    if 'remoteUrls' in value:
        url = value['remoteUrls']
        ref = value['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1']
        new_dict['url'] = url
        new_dict['ref'] = ref
        print new_dict
```

results:

```
{
    'url': [u'ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'],
    'ref': u'194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'
}
{
    'url': [u'ssh://def:29418/def.git'],
    'ref': u'7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'
}
```

I want to join the results into one dictionary and the desired output is like this:

```
{
    vcs1: {
        'url': [u'ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'],
        'ref': u'194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'
    },
    vcs2: {
        'url': [u'ssh://def:29418/def.git'],
        'ref': u'7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'
    }
}
```

Is there any way to achieve the desired output? Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Where do `vcs1` and `vcs2` come from? Can there be more?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one way:

```
lst = [{'url': [u'ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'],'ref':u'194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'}, 
       {'url': [u'ssh://def:29418/def.git'], 'ref': u'7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'}]

i = (i for i in range(len(lst)))
d = {'vcs{}'.format(next(i) + 1): x for x in lst}

print(d)
# {'vcs1': {'url': ['ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'], 'ref': '194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'}, 
#  'vcs2': {'url': ['ssh://def:29418/def.git'], 'ref': '7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'}}
```

Or using [`itertools.count`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.count) as suggested in comments:

```
from itertools import count

lst = [{'url':[u'ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'],'ref':u'194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'}, 
       {'url': [u'ssh://def:29418/def.git'], 'ref': u'7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'}]

i = count(1)
d = {'vcs{}'.format(next(i)): x for x in lst}

print(d)
# {'vcs1': {'url': ['ssh://abc.com:29418/abc.git'], 'ref': '194d4c418c71f77355117bd253cf2ac9849b25dd'}, 
#  'vcs2': {'url': ['ssh://def:29418/def.git'], 'ref': '7a198bf01b73330c379cc54aae1631f4448a4b0b'}}
```

Or this is even simple using [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate):

```
d = {'vcs{}'.format(i): x for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)}
```

Comment: You can use `itertools.count` instead of the generator expression in `i`. But works fine regardless.

Comment: Or `d = {'vcs{}'.format(i): x for i, x in enumerate(lst, 1)}` -- don't need the generator, it was an odd choice.

Comment: Thanks @FHTMitchell , I think that's better than my previous answer. :)

Comment: Thanks guys. It is working like a charm . I learned a new Python module itertools. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: sure @Austin. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

There are some easy methods,

- dict.update() will help you join dictionaries.

> ```
> >>> a = dict()
> >>> a.update({1:2})
> >>> a
> {1: 2}
> >>> a.update({3:4})
> >>> a
> {1: 2, 3: 4}
> ```

- dict['key'] = {'url':['URL'], 'ref':'REF'}

> ```
> >>> a['key123'] = {'url':['url1','url2'], 'ref':'REF'}
> >>> a
> {1: 2, 'key1': {'a': 'hello'}, 3: 4, 'key123': {'url': ['url1', 'url2'], 'ref': 'REF'}, 'key2': {'url': ['URL1', 'URL2'], 'ref': u'ref'}}
> ```

As per your case,

```
res = dict()
for value in data['actions']:
    if 'remoteUrls' in value:
        res['key_name'] = {'url':value['remoteUrls'] ,
                           'ref':value['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1']}
print res # check the entries
```

- dict comprehension

`dict(dict(<key>, {'url':value['remoteUrls'], 'ref':value['lastBuiltRevision']['SHA1']} for value in data['actions'] if 'remoteUrls' in value)`